# Java Maven works in Eclipse but don't work in OpenShift

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, openshift

I have built a java maven project. In Eclipse I can run a "clean install" and it works fine. 
Now I am new with OpenShift and I want to run there this application. I have chosen the "Red Hat Open JDK 8" and pull the code from my git repository. Now when I build my application, it don't install because of a compliation failure.
Here are the errors from the log:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[3,26] package javafx.application does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[4,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[6,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[7,20] package javafx.stage does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[9,37] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Application
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Stage
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.MainController
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[15,27] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Stage
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.MainController
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[25,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[26,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[27,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[28,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[29,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[30,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[31,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[35,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[36,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[37,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[38,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[39,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[40,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[41,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[42,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[43,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[44,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[45,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[46,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[47,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[48,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[49,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[50,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[51,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[52,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[53,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[54,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[55,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[56,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[57,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[58,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[59,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[60,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[61,5] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class FXML
location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[INFO] 110 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29.523 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-14T09:12:58Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/458M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project PricingCalculator: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/AzureRateCard.java:[171,137] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/AzureRateCard.java:[196,79] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/AzureRateCard.java:[197,180] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[28,68] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[28,85] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[28,108] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[28,120] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[42,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[56,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[70,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[77,73] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[84,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[98,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[112,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[126,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[140,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[154,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/CSVWriter.java:[168,115] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[15,26] package javafx.beans.value does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[16,26] package javafx.beans.value does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[17,1] package javafx.collections does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[18,20] package javafx.event does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[19,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[20,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[21,1] package javafx.scene.control does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[23,36] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Initializable
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[25,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ListView
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[26,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[27,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[28,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[29,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[30,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[31,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[32,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[33,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[34,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[35,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[36,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[37,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[38,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[39,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[40,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[41,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ChoiceBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[42,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CheckBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[43,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CheckBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[44,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CheckBox
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[45,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[46,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[47,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[48,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[49,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[50,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[51,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[52,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[53,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[54,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Label
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[55,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[56,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[57,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[58,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Button
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[59,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TextField
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[60,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TextField
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[61,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class TextField
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[1666,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Event
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[3,26] package javafx.application does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[4,19] package javafx.fxml does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[5,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[6,20] package javafx.scene does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[7,20] package javafx.stage does not exist
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[9,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Application
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Stage
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.MainController
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[12,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Parent
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.MainController
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/MainController.java:[15,27] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Stage
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.MainController
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[25,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[26,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[27,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[28,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[29,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[30,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[31,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[32,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[33,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[34,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[35,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[36,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[37,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[38,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[39,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[40,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[41,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[42,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[43,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[44,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[45,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[46,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[47,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[48,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[49,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[50,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[51,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[52,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[53,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[54,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[55,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[56,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[57,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[58,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[59,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[60,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] /tmp/src/src/main/java/com/nttdata/altemista/Controller.java:[61,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FXML
[ERROR]   location: class com.nttdata.altemista.Controller
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project PricingCalculator: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException 
Aborting due to error code 1 for Maven build
error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:78af15475eac13d2ff439b33a9c3bdd39147858a824c420e8042fd5f35adce15
```

It's a javafx project.

I hope somebody can help me.
If you need some more information please ask. How I said, I'm new with OpenShift and don't know what is important.

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I thought if my application works in Eclipse it will also works in OpenShift. Maybe you are right and first I need to learn the entire "Openshift Environment"

Comment: your eclipse installation is completely local. It contains plugins, dependencies, ... basically everything you configure it to have. Now, I have no idea why you try to run a mvn clean install in openshift ... normally, you should just deploy your already built project

Comment: Try running mvn clean install from command line. It looks like Eclipse might be adding dependencies which are not declared in the pom files. Also check for warnings. There might be some problems with downloading dependencies. Also check if the JDK in Eclipse matches JDK in your container.

Comment: Probably I express it wrong. In openshift I only build my application which is connected with my git repository.

Comment: JavaFX is not part of the OpenJDK you need to install it separately.